# Auto redirect google code to github

Tags: github, google-code

[We](http://www.openworm.org/) have moved [our codebase and wiki](https://github.com/openworm/OpenWorm) to github. However [the google code version](https://code.google.com/p/openworm/) still shows up really high on Google. Is there any way to do an auto redirect to github when people land on the Google code version?

Comment: Redirects like that are usually handled by the underlying server, like Apache or Nginx.  I don't think there's a way for you to do that implicitly.

Comment: Server side redirects are out, so is javascript or meta refresh.   I don't think it can be done.

Comment: App hosting issue, not about code, but about webpage hosting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how long this option has been available (it may be related to [Google announcing they're shutting down Google Code](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html)), but you can now [set a "project moved" flag](https://code.google.com/p/support-tools/wiki/GitHubExporterFAQ#Setting_the_%22Project_Moved%22_Flag) which will provide all visitors to your Google Code project with a link to any other site, including GitHub.

**Note:** It doesn't appear that you can fully revert this setting, at least not at the time of my writing this, so be sure you really don't want to access anything from the Google Code project before setting it.

Comment: This is not possible. adminAdvanced gives us no control over the project. Contacting google-code-shutdown@google.com does not help.

Answer (score 1):

You can [mark your project as moved](https://code.google.com/p/support-tools/wiki/GitHubExporterFAQ#Setting_the_%22Project_Moved%22_Flag) on your admin page. If you change your mind, you can clear the setting by clicking the publish button.

> ### Setting the "Project Moved" Flag
>
> Once a project has been successfully exported to GitHub, you will want to update your project's homepage on Google Code to avoid confusion.
>
> Some project owners simply update their project homepage's text to indicate it has moved to GitHub. For example subtext or bwapi.
>
> Another option is to set the Google Code "project moved" flag. When set, attempts to access the project will take users to an interstitial page indicating the new project location. In the future, the page will automatically redirect to well-known project hosting services such as github.com.
>
> To set the "project moved" flag, navigate to your project's advanced admin page, at https://code.google.com/p//adminAdvanced.
>
> Once there, enter the new project home page URL under "project moved". For example: https://github.com/google/kythe. Finally click the "Project Moved" button.
>
> If you need to "un-move" a project, you can go back to the /adminAdvanced page at a later time and click "Publish". This will restore your project to its original state, before the move.

Comment: This is not possible. adminAdvanced gives us no control over the project. I have a project that is being automatically redirected, and is not archived, and other that is not redirected and is archived (both moved to GIT by the site tool)